# PowerShell: append string to result of Get-ADUser query

Tags: powershell, active-directory, select-object

I want to attach a string to a Get-ADUser object.

```
$VALUE =  "Something : Else " 

$RESULT = Get-ADUser -Filter 'givenName -eq "Joe" ' -Property * | 
             Select-Object -Property givenName, Surname, "$VALUE"
```

I got some bracket { } instead of "Else"

```
PS C:\> $RESULT 
givenName                  : Joe
Surname                    : Black
Something : Else           : {}
```

But I want this here!

```
PS C:\> $RESULT 
givenName                  : Joe
Surname                    : Black
Something                  : Else
```

I try to put the Get-ADUser object into a string array and then attach $VALUE but that doesn't works.

Has anybody a idea?

Because I have to save it into a CSV file.

```
$RESULT | Export-CSV $DESTINATION -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ';'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-5.1) uses hashtables with a `Name`/`Label` and `Expression` key (which you can shorten to `n` and `e`).

`Name` must be a string (the name of your custom property), and `Expression` must be a scriptblock.

```
# long version
Select-Object -Property GivenName, Surname, @{Name = "Something"; Expression = {"Else"}}
# short version
select GivenName, Surname, @{n="Something";e={"Else"}}
```

Comment: 2 schools... name or label :) I prefer label, but you are right, name seems more suitable :)

Comment: Excellent answer, but one caveat - `Expression` value can also be a `[string]`, in which case it'll evaluate to the value of an existing named property (useful for "renaming" properties)